# Select all if parameter is null or return selected values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table(just for reference, the original table has thousands of records):

```
+-------+------------+--------+
| Brand | Categories | Amount |
+-------+------------+--------+
|  ABC  |  Cat1      | 779    |
|  DEF  |  Cat2      | 543    |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

I am creating a `temp table` in a procedure which pulls values if the parameters match.

```
create proc PROCNAME @Brand nvarchar(max), @Category nvarchar(max) as

create table #table1(VALUES)
insert into #table1(VALUES)
select amount 
from OriginalTable
where @Brand in (Select value from fn_split(@Brand,',')) or @Brand is null
and @Category in (Select value from fn_split(@Category,',')) or @Category is null
```

The `fn_split` passes comma seperated values.

I need something where if the parameter passes a null value then it will `SELECT ALL` values of them else whatever is passed.

I know the code I'm using for the `is null` condition is wrong but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are about 1,000 questions that cover this topic on SO alone,
 but I doubt you will find anything as comprehensive as Erland Sommarskog,'s [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: You also may find that using [table valued parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.110).aspx) is much better option than passing delimited strings to the procedure

Comment: Basically, you need parentheses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, forgot to add them here but that isn't the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where @Brand in (Select value from fn_split(@Brand,',')) or @Brand is null or @Brand=''
and @Category in (Select value from fn_split(@Category,',')) or @Category is null or @Category= ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using dynamic SQL:

```
create proc PROCNAME 
    @Brand nvarchar(max)
  , @Category nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

create table #table1(VALUES)

SET @sql = N'insert into #table1(VALUES)
             select amount 
             from OriginalTable
             where 1 = 1 ' 
        + CASE WHEN @Brand IS NOT NULL THEN 
            N' AND Brand in (Select value from fn_split(@Brand,'','')) ' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @Category IS NOT NULL THEN 
            N' AND Category in (Select value from fn_split(@Category,'',''))' ELSE N'' END

Exec sp_executesql @sql
                  , N'@Brand nvarchar(max) , @Category nvarchar(max)'
                  , @Brand
                  , @Category
END
GO
```

### Problem with Other approach

There is a major issue with this other approach, you write your where clause something like...

```
WHERE ( Brand = @Brand  OR @Brand is null)
```

The Two major issues with this approach

1) you cannot force SQL Server to check evaluate an expression first like if `@Brand is null`, Sql Server might decide to evaluate first  the expression `Brand = @Brand`so you will have where clause being evaluated even if the variable value is null.

2) SQL Server does not do Short-Circuiting, if even if it decides to check the `Brand = @Brand` expression first and even if it evaluates to true, SQL Server still may go ahead and evaluating other expression in `OR` clause.

Therefore stick to Dynamic Sql for queries like this. and happy days.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify WHERE clause as below

```
WHERE (@Brand IS NULL OR Brand IN (Select value from fn_split(@Brand,','))) AND 
      (@Category IS NULL OR Category IN (Select value from fn_split(@Category,',')))
```